# O que é porta lógica do usuário em PHP?

Tags: php, ip

O que é "porta lógica"? E como detectar a porta lógica do usuário usando PHP?
Seria isso?

```
$porta = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
```

Fonte: https://www.migalhas.com.br/quentes/275632/facebook-e-condenado-a-fornecer-porta-logica-de-origem-para-identificacao-de-usuarios

Answer (score 6):

Portas físicas são as conexões físicas de dispositivos, como por exemplo um conector RJ-45 de um roteador ou modem.

As portas lógicas são portas de conexões lógicas identificadas por um número, que servem para conectar a um serviço, TCP ou UDP num dispositivo (servidor, computador, etc).

Uma boa analogia seria, imagina que você tem um prédio comercial. Ele tem um endereço (Rua XXX, nr 1). Esse seria por exemplo o endereço IP do servidor. Uma vez que entra no prédio, você pode ir a diversos lugares, com várias salas. Cada sala ou apartamento seria uma porta lógica (Rua XXX, nr1, Sala 10).

Quando se acessa um serviço Web (HTTP) de um site, em geral ele responde pela porta lógica 80, um serviço *FTP*, na porta lógica 21, e assim por diante.

As portas lógicas vão de 0 até 65535, e são divididas em três grupos:

- **Well-Known Ports**: vão de 0 a 1023. São os serviços mais comuns e usadas como padrão, como por exemplo, porta 80 para serviços Web HTTP e port 443 para serviços Web HTTPS.
- **Registered Ports**: vão de 1024 a 49151. São serviços geralmente internos dos servidores, são registradas para serviços como autenticação, proxy, e bancos de dados entre outros. O *SQL Server* por exemplo usa a porta 1433 por padrão.
- **Dynamic Ports**: vão de 49152 a 65535. São portas dinâmicas que geralmente variam para cada conexão. São usadas para conexões temporárias, como por exemplo quando se conecta a um jogo, ou *peers* de *Torrent* quando está fazendo download/upload.

Aqui uma lista completa das portas "bem conhecidas": https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_portas_dos_protocolos_TCP_e_UDP

Agora voltando ao PHP. No seu exemplo está usando o `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']`. Isso irá te retornar a porta a qual está conectado no servidor.

Comment: a porta lógica não é do usuário, é do server! lembre-se que o php é executado no lado server, então ele vai mostrar a porta que o server disponibilizou para o usuário se conectar a ele. Não sei se ficou claro, na prática é a porta onde o server e o usuário estão se comunicando